# Export gpodder subscription list via command line

Tags: command-line, console, gpodder

Unfortunately it seems a recent system upgrade broke my graphics card driver, so I am going to hard-reinstall the latest Ubuntu Version (18.04). Before I do that I want to export my gpodder podcast subscriptions. Due to the problem above I can only login via the console (Ctrl+Alt+F...), "and not GUI-wise".
What I'm asking for is probably laid out in the official gpodder documentation https://gpodder.github.io/, but because I'm not really literate in this kind of computer stuff, could someone please lay out to me which sequence of commands I have to enter to store those in an OPML (or whichever format is best) file in, say, my home directory?

Comment: Are you planning to remove your home directory when you reinstall the OS? I'm asking that because gpodder stores its settings in your home folder by default – if you're not going to remove `/home` anyway, but will use it in the new installation as well, there's no need to do anything to keep the settings *including* your subscriptions. If your going to remove your home folder however it's a bit unclear why you would want to “save” the subscriptions there – they'd be removed as well of course. Or did you change gpodders settings path in any way? Please [edit] and clarify on the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter `gpo`

You will get

```
gPodder 3.10.1 (2018-02-19) - http://gpodder.org/
Copyright 2005-2018 The gPodder Team
License: GNU General Public License, version 3 or later

Entering interactive shell. Type 'help' for help.
Press Ctrl+D (EOF) or type 'quit' to quit.
```

After typing help, you will see that you need to enter

```
export backup.opml
```

type exit to exit the interactive mode

The file backup.opml will be saved in your home folder.

You can also enter:

```
gpo export backup.opml
```